# Constructing sequelize query with multiple tables and aliases

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I have the next query:

```
SELECT ul.createdAt, ul.userId, l.url, l.caption FROM links AS l, userLinks AS ul WHERE ul.userId = 1 AND ul.linkId = l.id ORDER BY ul.createdAt DESC;
```

I have tried multiple ways to translate this into sequelize but none has proven to be successful.

Right now I have a model called `links` and another one called `userLinks`, I have read sequelize's documentation and some other threads on this but can not get it to work properly.

How I am constructing my query

```
Link.findAll({
    order: [[UserLink, 'createdAt', 'DESC']],
    attributes: ['caption', 'id', 'url'],
    limit: 15,
    include: [
        {
            model: UserLink,
            attributes: ['createdAt'],
            where: {
                userId,
                linkId: Sequelize.col('links.id')
            }
        },
        {
            model: User,
            attributes: ['id', 'name', 'about', 'username', 'picture']
        }
    ]
})
```

and

```
Link.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserLink });
User.belongsToMany(Link, { through: UserLink });
```

Error I was getting

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: user_link is not associated to link!
```

I realize that `UserLink` itself is the association table between User and Links and that is why it is not associated but I need to order the resulted links by the transitive table's **createdAt** and be able to get the user.

Comment: Did you get any error ? Also add your model here

Comment: You will get better answers if you post some of your attempts and your models, as @Priyank says.  Essentially you will need 1) to make an association between userLinks and links, such as `userLinks.belongsTo(links, {foreignKey: linkId, targetKey: id});` and 2) to query userLinks and include links, too, such as `userLinks.findAll({where: { userId : 1}}, include: {model: links, required : true} });`

Comment: added details and added bounty.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you provided your models and an example of the result you want to achieve, kinda confused here cause in your query you are not fetching anything from the users table, while in the sequelize implementation you are, but i think the sequelize implementation represents what you need, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have defined your models like this:

```
Link.hasMany(UserLinks, { foreignKey: 'link_id', as: 'userLinks' });
UserLink.belongsTo(Link, { foreignKey: 'link_id', as 'link' });
```

The query will be:

```
Link.findAll({
  attributes: ['caption', 'id', 'url'],
  order: [['userLinks', 'created_at', 'DESC']],
  limit: 15,
  include: [
    {
      model: UserLink,
      as: 'userLinks',
      attributes: ['created_at'],
      required: true,
      where: { userId }
    },
  ],
});
```

Note that you should use `require: true`, otherwise `Sequelize` will build `LEFT JOIN`.